# Prime Numbers in given range with Java-8

Tags: java, java-8

I am writing a program to calculate the number of prime numbers in a given range.

My code is as below:

```
public class MultiLineInput {
    static int k=0;
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberOfLinesToRead =  2;//  s.nextInt();
        int []  array = new int [numberOfLinesToRead];
            for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
                array[i]=s.nextInt();
            }
        List<Integer> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(array[0], array[1]).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        IntStream.rangeClosed(array[0], array[1]).boxed().map(k -> {
           if(BigInteger.valueOf(list.get(k)).isProbablePrime(1)==true){
               k++;
               return true;
           }
              return false;
        });
        System.out.println(k);

    }
}
```

**The input is as follows:**

```
1
20
```

**Output:**

```
0
```

**Expected Output:**

```
8
```

Comment: You shouldn't name all your variables `k`. Soon you don't know which `k` you're incrementing...

Comment: And never use something like `condition==true`. Just use `if(condition) …`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two `k` variables.

One is `static` which you never change, so it remains `0`.

The other, which you increment inside the `Stream` pipeline is a local variable, so incrementing it has no effects after the pipeline is done.

In addition, your second `Stream` pipeline has no terminal operation, so it doesn't process the elements of the `Stream`.

Also, I suggest not to use side effects (i.e. incrementing a `static` variable) inside the `Stream` pipeline. Use `filter` instead of `map` and count the number of elements in the filtered `Stream`:

```
long result = IntStream.range(array[0], array[1])
                       .boxed()
                       .filter(n -> BigInteger.valueOf(n).isProbablePrime(1))
                       .count();
```

Note that your first `Stream` pipeline (which produces a `List`) is not necessary.

Comment: And the entire array is obsolete too. The code populating it looks like being adaptable to different sizes but the subsequent use can’t do anything useful with a different number than two. So why not just use `IntStream.range(s.nextInt(), s.nextInt())`…